# How to send a post request via postman to nested writable serializer in django-rest-framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, postman

I'm really struggling with sending my data with postman in correct form to my Django backend. I followed the approach in the Django documentation for a [writeable nested Seralizer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers) and adapted it to my case. If I pass the data to my serializer via the shell, everything works and I can create the two object instances `Story` and `File`. But if I try to do the same with post man, it is not successful and receive the following error Message: `Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field 'file' on serializer 'StoryCreateUpdateSerializer'. The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the 'Story' instance. Original exception text was: 'Story' object has no attribute 'file'.`

Successfull Request via Shell:

```
>>> data = {
    'title': 'HALLLO',
    'file': [
        {'content': 'Public Service Announcement'},
        {'content': 'Public Service Announcement'},
        {'content': 'Public Service Announcement'},
    ],
}
>>> serializer = StoryCreateUpdateSerializer(data=data)
>>> serializer.is_valid()
True
>>> serializer.save()
```

Not Successfull Request via Postman. Header: Content-Type: application/json. Body: Raw

```
{
    "title": "Test",
    "file": [
        {
            "content": "Hallo"
        }
    ]
}
```

My models and Serializers

```
#MODELS
class Story (models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

class File(models.Model):
    story = models.ForeignKey(Story,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    content = models.TextField(blank=False, null=True)
#SERIALIZER
class TestFileSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = File
        fields =  ('content',)

class StoryCreateUpdateSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer):
    file = TestFileSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Story
        fields =  ('title','file')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        current_user = self.context["request"].user
        title = validated_data.pop('title')
        file = validated_data.pop('file')
        story_instance = Story.objects.create(author=current_user, title=title)

        for file_data in file:
            File.objects.create(**file_data, story=story_instance)
        return story_instance
#VIEW
class StoryCreateUpdateViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = StoryCreateUpdateSerializer

    queryset = Story.objects.all()
```

I'am happy for any clarification. As i running out of ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ForeignKey field of **File** model, default `related_name` and `related_query_name` attributes are **'file_set'** not **'file'**

So you should do one of these changes on your code:

**Method 1:**
In **File** model add `related_name` and `related_query_name` attributes to ForeignKey field with values **'file'**:

```py
story = models.ForeignKey(
    Story,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    null=True,
    related_name = 'file',
    related_query_name = 'file'
)
```

**Method 2:**
In `StoryCreateUpdateSerializer` change **'file'** field to **'file_set'**:

```py
class StoryCreateUpdateSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer):
    file_set = TestFileSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Story
        fields =  ('title','file_set')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        current_user = self.context["request"].user
        title = validated_data.pop('title')
        file = validated_data.pop('file')
        story_instance = Story.objects.create(author=current_user, title=title)

        for file_data in file:
            File.objects.create(**file_data, story=story_instance)
        return story_instance
```

In this method, also you've to change your request body properties and substitute **'file'** with **'file_set'**